# Copying a template from Excel to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a template that is stationed in an excel file. Once I click the preview button, this template will be displayed in outlook as well as its subject, to and etc.

I have this code that works fine but is not working in the body field.

```
Sub previewMail()
Dim objMail, objOutLook As Object
Dim rngTo, rngCC, rngBCC, rngBody As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Integer


Set objOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutLook.CreateItem(0)
Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

lRow = main.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 11 To lRow
    With main
        Set rngTo = .Range("B" & i)
        Set rngBody = .Range(.Range("C10:N30"), .Range("C10:N30")) 
    End With

    With objMail
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .Subject = "Sample"
        'i like the rngbody to be here
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rngBody)' from Ron de Bruin site
        .Display

    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

This is the template stationed in the said range above.

[image]
Can anyone please help me figure this out? I have tried [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) from Ron de Bruin but I can't make it work. This only gives a product that is an "invisible table".

Comment: Are you sure your code for setting rngBody is correct? Its always pointing to `Range("C10:N30")`.

Comment: @Jochen Yes it is correct.

Comment: What is not working? I'm little confused

Comment: @Om3r The content of `.Range(.Range("C10:N30"), .Range("C10:N30")) ` is a template, and it is not included when i try to display the mail. I've included a picture of the contents of the said range

Comment: Can you show us what it looks like? `.Range(.Range("C10:N30"), .Range("C10:N30")) `

Comment: @Ramj, that looks like a textbox in your screenshot- is that the case?

Comment: @Om3r What do you mean?

Comment: @tompreston Yes, you're right.

Comment: Probably need to indicate that in the question, you're currrently trying to take info from a range of empty cells, you need to take it from a text box object, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193749.aspx)

Example

```
Option Explicit
Sub previewMail()
    Dim objMail, Main, objOutLook As Object
    Dim rngTo, rngCC, rngBCC, rngBody As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document '<---

    Set objOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutLook.CreateItem(0)
    Set Main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
    Set wordDoc = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor '<---

    lRow = Main.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 11 To lRow
        With Main
            Set rngTo = .Range("B" & i)
            Set rngBody = .Range(.Range("C10:N30"), .Range("C10:N30"))
            rngBody.Copy '<---
        End With

        With objMail
            .To = rngTo.Value
            .Subject = "Sample"
            .Display
             wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture '<---
             ' Or
             'wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture & .HTMLBody = " "
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Make sure to set references to the Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Word **`Object`** libraries

<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>References...</kbd>

[image]

Comment: @ramj is this what you trying to do?

Comment: This is one of the great idea, but is there any other way that the body is editable?

Comment: @ramj Okay try `wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture & .HTMLBody = " "`

Comment: Is there any way we can delete the contents of that range in the excel? Thanks.

Comment: @ramj Have Try something like `rngBody.ClearContents` at the very end. outside the loop

Comment: @ramj it worked for me, okay can you share the spreadsheet? I would like to see  how you created template.

Comment: How can I share the sheet to you?

Comment: Is there any way I can add a signature after the template in outlook? Because if i add the signature, it is only overridden by the template. Thanks

Comment: @ramj Can you post new Question please.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: OP has indicated text is not in range, but in a textbox in front of range.

Use this code to find the textbox name:

```
for i = 1 to activesheet.chartobjects.count
    debug.print chartobjects(i).name
next i
```

It will be like Textbox1 or something, then use(untested):

```
dim strBody as string
Set strBody = activesheet.chartobjects("Textbox1").Value
.HTMLBody = strbody
```

Comment: This returns an error`This member can only be accessed for a Chart Object`