# Adding the commonly used signature after the template

Tags: vba, excel, templates, outlook

I have this problem that if I have to add a signature in my Outlook Mail through Excel VBA, the signature is not included. It is only overridden by the template. If you ask how did I insert the template, please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848812/copying-a-template-from-excel-to-outlook/38868279?noredirect=1#comment65362714_38868279), this is my previous question. And my problem now is to insert a signature after the template.  This is what I've tried so far:

```
Dim objMail as Object, attach as object, wordDoc as Word.Document
Dim main as Worksheet, rngBody as Range

set main = Thisworkbook.sheets("Main")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    Set attach = objMail.attachments
    Set wordDoc = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With main
        Set rngBody = .Range(.Range("B12:M31"), .Range("B12:M31"))
        rngBody.Copy
    End With

    With objMail
        .Subject = "Sample"
        .To = "chu@chuchu.com"
        wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture & .htmlbody = " " 

'I've tried this 3 instances         
        signature = objMail.body
        '.body = signature
        'htmlBody = signature  
        .Display
    End With
```

Am I on the right path or not? Because all of that is only overridden by the template. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First store the signature then add it later.

```
Sub sig()

    Dim objMail As mailItem
    Dim signature As String

    Set objMail = CreateItem(0)

    With objMail

        .Display    ' This is necessary to generate the default signature
        signature = objMail.HTMLBody
        Debug.Print signature

        ' Having saved the signature, you can manipulate the body
        .HTMLBody = "test"

        ' Now you can add the saved signature to the end
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & signature

    End With

End Sub
```